# how to concat array2 to array1 correctly with splice

Tags: javascript, arrays

in this example i want to concat or append array2 to array1 with splice , it is return empty array but it should return all values in the two arrays

[the example link](http://jsfiddle.net/Qq2aM/717/)

```
var obj = [{"id":"36","task_name":"task1","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"37","task_name":"task2","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"38","task_name":"task3","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"39","task_name":"task4","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"40","task_name":"task5","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"41","task_name":"task6","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"42","task_name":"task7","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"43","task_name":"task8","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"44","task_name":"task9","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"45","task_name":"task10","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"}];

var obj2 = [{"id":"46","task_name":"task11","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"47","task_name":"task12","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"48","task_name":"task13","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"49","task_name":"task14","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"50","task_name":"task15","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"51","task_name":"task16","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"52","task_name":"task17","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"53","task_name":"task18","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"54","task_name":"task19","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"55","task_name":"task20","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"}];


var arr = Object.values(obj);
var arr2 = Object.values(obj2);
var fin = arr.splice(10,0,...arr2)
console.log(fin );
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat  might make more sense for this use case.

Comment: splice returns the parts of the array you removed, not the newly reformed array.

Comment: What's the outcome you're after. You've created a variable `fin`, but your logging `arr`. Do you want the combined array to be a new array, or just added to `arr`?

Comment: @zfrisch if you give it a delete count of 0, splice can add new elements.  Edit: though for an addition, the returned array is empty.

Comment: sorry i updated the example , i want to return fin ,which compine the two arrays

Comment: `splice` only returns deleted elements. Since you're not deleting anything, `fin` is an empty array.

Comment: keep in mind that `splice` *modifies the original array.* https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Comment: so jerermy why it not modfiy the original array,how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already using the spread operator, why not just use it for both arrays? Also you don't need `Object.values` since you're starting with arrays - that would be more appropriate if these were objects.

```js
var obj = [{"id":"36","task_name":"task1","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"37","task_name":"task2","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"38","task_name":"task3","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"39","task_name":"task4","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"40","task_name":"task5","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"41","task_name":"task6","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"42","task_name":"task7","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"43","task_name":"task8","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"44","task_name":"task9","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"45","task_name":"task10","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"}];
var obj2 = [{"id":"46","task_name":"task11","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"47","task_name":"task12","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"48","task_name":"task13","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"49","task_name":"task14","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"50","task_name":"task15","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"51","task_name":"task16","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"52","task_name":"task17","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"53","task_name":"task18","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"54","task_name":"task19","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"55","task_name":"task20","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"}];

var fin = [...obj,...obj2]
console.log(fin);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this without using `splice()`

```js
var obj = [{"id":"36","task_name":"task1","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"37","task_name":"task2","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"38","task_name":"task3","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"39","task_name":"task4","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"40","task_name":"task5","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"41","task_name":"task6","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"42","task_name":"task7","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"43","task_name":"task8","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"44","task_name":"task9","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"45","task_name":"task10","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"}];

var obj2 = [{"id":"46","task_name":"task11","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"47","task_name":"task12","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"48","task_name":"task13","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"49","task_name":"task14","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"50","task_name":"task15","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"51","task_name":"task16","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"52","task_name":"task17","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"53","task_name":"task18","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"54","task_name":"task19","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"55","task_name":"task20","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"}];

console.log(obj.concat(obj2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that `Array.concat()` seems to give the expected result:

```js
var obj = [{"id":"36","task_name":"task1","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"37","task_name":"task2","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"38","task_name":"task3","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"39","task_name":"task4","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"40","task_name":"task5","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"41","task_name":"task6","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"42","task_name":"task7","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"43","task_name":"task8","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"44","task_name":"task9","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"45","task_name":"task10","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"}];

var obj2 = [{"id":"46","task_name":"task11","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"47","task_name":"task12","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"48","task_name":"task13","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"49","task_name":"task14","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"50","task_name":"task15","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"51","task_name":"task16","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"52","task_name":"task17","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"53","task_name":"task18","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"54","task_name":"task19","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"55","task_name":"task20","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"}];

var fin = obj.concat(obj2)
console.log(fin);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```js
var obj = [{"id":"36","task_name":"task1","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"37","task_name":"task2","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"38","task_name":"task3","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"39","task_name":"task4","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"40","task_name":"task5","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"41","task_name":"task6","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"42","task_name":"task7","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"43","task_name":"task8","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"44","task_name":"task9","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"45","task_name":"task10","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"}];

var obj2 = [{"id":"46","task_name":"task11","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"47","task_name":"task12","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"48","task_name":"task13","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"49","task_name":"task14","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"50","task_name":"task15","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"51","task_name":"task16","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"52","task_name":"task17","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"53","task_name":"task18","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"54","task_name":"task19","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"},{"id":"55","task_name":"task20","birth_date":"2018-06-15 00:00:00","is_completed":"0"}];

[].push.apply(obj, obj2);
console.log(obj);
```